# django - How to get parameters from "def save" function

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get parameters from the "save" function? Even if I shoot debug,
models.py

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo?h=2020&w=8020`

I have to save using "h=2020&file_w=8020".
Adding "request" gives me an error.

Comment: What is the error you get from adding "request"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print the data inside of it like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`args` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple) with the arguments and `kwargs` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with the keyword arguments.

Example:

```
function('this is an argument', this_is_keyword='value of keyword')
```